# Passing variables into a tkinter class window

Tags: python, class, variables, tkinter, multiprocessing

I want to create a GUI in tkinter that not only executes commands when a button is pressed, but responds to the state of a larger script running in a separate thread.

I have really dug around and tried to find some information on message passing, and I have found some great info on the pickle module, using multiprocessing and its built in tools and also threading, and queuing.  I have even dug into David Beazley's lesson on concurrency located [here.](https://www.slideshare.net/dabeaz/an-introduction-to-python-concurrency?from_action=save) I just can't get the syntax right on any of those methods.

I have broken down my code into a small functional unit that should launch a little tkinter window like this:

[tkinter window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuRGY.png)

The code below has a "launchGUI" function that launches my tkinter GUI, a "myLoop" function that starts the threads and will also loop to drive my larger program later, right now it just rotates the blink variable.  I also have a blinkCheck method in my class that checks the status of the blink variable in the class.

I don't know if I am even putting my message receiver in the right place.  In the following example code I am just trying to pass a global variable into the class. I know it is getting into the class, because the blinkCheck() method works even though uncommenting that method crashes the window.  However, with the method turned off the label in the GUI never changes.  I think the window crashing is the least of my worries, it must be because i have another while loop running.

What is the correct way to get that number in Label to change?

Here is my example code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Frame, Label
import time
import threading

blink = 0

class MyClass(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        super().__init__(self.master)

        global blink  

        self.label = Label(master, text=blink)
        self.label.pack()
        #self.blinkCheck()

    def blinkCheck(self):
        global blink
        while True:
            print("blink in blinkCheck method is = {}".format(blink))
            time.sleep(2.5)

def launchGUI():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("My Blinker")
    app1 = MyClass(root)
    app1.mainloop()

def myLoop():
    global blink
    t1=threading.Thread(target=launchGUI)
    t1.daemon = True
    t1.start()
    print("blink in blinker function is {}".format(blink))
    while True:
        if blink == 0:
            blink = 1
        else:
            if blink == 1:
                blink = 0
        time.sleep(2.5)


if __name__=="__main__":
    myLoop()
```

Comment: Don't create Tk instances in threads, only in the main program.

Answer (score 0):

In your description you have mentioned something about involving buttons. I do not see that in your provided snippet. But with buttons it is possible to configure the label, i.e:

```
from tkinter import Label, Button
blink = 0

class MyClass(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        super().__init__(self.master)

        global blink  

        self.label = Label(master, text=blink)
        self.button = Button(master, text="Button", command=lambda: foo(self.label))
        self.label.pack()
        self.button.pack()
        #self.blinkCheck()

    def blinkCheck(self):
        global blink
        while True:
            print("blink in blinkCheck method is = {}".format(blink))
            time.sleep(2.5)

    def foo(self, label):
        label.config(text=blink)
```

Conventionally, this would be the most simple way to configure a label within an active thread.

If anyone feels like this answer may not be fully correct, please do edit it because I am new to Stack Overflow!

Comment: `label` is bound to `self`. so no need to use `lambda: foo(self.label)`.

Comment: Thank you Arrush.  I had to add a few lines to your code, but the label still does not blink.  I'm not as interested in adding buttons yet, my main goal is to update something on the GUI to show that it is still communicating with myLoop().  Later I will make it a blinking light or something, but I want to be able to look at my GUI and see that it is communicating with myLoop() at a glance.  Moreover, I want a two way interface with myLoop() eventually, but I'm just taking baby steps!

Answer (score 0):

First, the GUI must run in main thread, and must not blocked by a infinite loop. Use `after` instead. To communicate, use some appropriate object from threading, e.g. Event:

```
import tkinter as tk
import time
import threading

class MyClass(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, event):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.event = event

        self.label = tk.Label(master, text='')
        self.label.pack()
        self.after(100, self.blink_check)

    def blink_check(self):
        self.label['text'] = self.event.is_set()
        self.after(100, self.blink_check)

def blink(event):
    while True:
        event.set()
        time.sleep(2.5)
        event.clear()
        time.sleep(2.5)

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("My Blinker")
    event = threading.Event()
    t = threading.Thread(target=blink, args=(event,))
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
    frame = MyClass(root, event)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks, that was very useful and I've been mulling it since you posted.  I think queuing is the direction  that I need to take because I will also need to pass more than a binary true/false into the thread eventually.  I'm working on that now, I hope you'll comment on it when I post it.